# How to include external database in phpfox

Tags: php, database, phpfox

I want to select some information from other server database into my existing phpfox project.Please help me out this how I can manage it.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What have you already tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ADDING ADITIONAL TABLES TO PHPFOX DATABASE IS OK TECHNICALLY** (It may void your warranty, check that before you proceed): Its alright to try to get other data from another external database to your existing PHPFOX project. What I would do, is import your new table into existing working dabatase.  Lets say you import a table with data into a newly created table inside the PHPFOX database. Then you can access it directly with your credentials already setup. (No need to open a new database). For instance, you have Drivers Licence information for each user, then you could easely link up driver licence records to any other template page that you develop. I have done it with ID tables to display real ID names next to the ones users input to verify is a user is not using his real profile. You can add as many tables as you wish inside your PHPFOX database, as long as you dont mess with the structure. Even you can add columns to existing tables. What you cant do is remove tables o columns already existing ones.  Let me know if you need any further support. Good Luck

Comment: If you want to import some data from PHPFOX previous versions to your current project, then you need to do an uptate, thats a different process.

Answer (score 0):

Database settings can be accessed at `/include/setting/server.sett.php` on phpFox v3 or at `/PF.Base/file/settings/server.sett.php` on phpFox v4. Simply change:

- `$_CONF['db']['user']` (username)
- `$_CONF['db']['pass']` (password)
- `$_CONF['db']['name']` (database name)
- `$_CONF['db']['port']` (port if your other database is on other port, 3306 is default)